# ¿Es posible poner icono de navegador como fuente?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Quiero cambiar el icono que aparece en la pestaña de los navegadores, el encargado de cargar la imagen es:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="logo.ico" />
```

Pues ahora quiero cargar una fuente de bootstrap, tipo **glyphicon-plus:**

Mi pregunta es ¿es posible cargar una fuente como imagen en la barra del navegador?

[Iconos bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En realidad lo que cargas como icono en la pestaña es el favicon. Este es bastante limitado en cuanto a puntos que puedes poner.

Lo que se me ocurre que puedes hacer es poner en una imagen el logo que quieres (usando, por ejemplo [GIMP](http://gimp.org)) y usar alguna [herramienta web](http://realfavicongenerator.net/) para hacer la conversión.

Answer (score 1):

Pues creo que no es posible. Lo que puedes hacer es crear tu `favicon` a partir de la fuente que desees utilizar.

En [este enlace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#File_format_support) encontrarás los formatos soportados por cada navegador.